# Laravel Elixer not able to minify and version javascript files

Tags: gulp, laravel-5.1, minify, laravel-elixir

i am using laravel 5.1 elixer to manage, version, minify my application css and js

Below is my gulpfile.js

```
elixir(function (mix) {
    mix.less([
        'app.less',
        'creative.less',
        'mixins.less',
        'variables.less'
    ]).less([
        'dashboard.less',
        'component.less',
        'app-variables.less'
    ], 'public/css/dashboard.css')

    mix.scriptsIn('public/js/angular/controller', 'public/js/angular/appControllers.min.js');
    mix.scriptsIn('public/js/angular/service', 'public/js/angular/appServices.min.js');
    mix.scriptsIn('public/js/angular/directive', 'public/js/angular/appDerictives.min.js');

    mix.version([
        'public/css/dashboard.css',
        'public/css/app.css',
        'public/js/angular/appControllers.min.js',
        'public/js/angular/appServices.min.js',
        'public/js/angular/appDerictives.min.js'
    ]);
});
```

Everything works fine when i run the command `gulp`, i get the compiled files and also the versions files are now in the build folder.

The problem starts when i use `gulp --production`, When laravel starts the process is breaks when starting with scripts, below is the error -

```
events.js:141
 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
 ^
Error at new JS_Parse_Error (eval at <anonymous (/Users/apple/code/hireajackal/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:1534:18)
at js_error (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/apple/code/hireajackal/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:1542:11)
at croak (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/apple/code/hireajackal/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2089:9)
at token_error (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/apple/code/hireajackal/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2097:9)
at unexpected (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/apple/code/hireajackal/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2103:9)
at expr_atom (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/apple/code/hireajackal/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2630:9)
at maybe_unary (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/apple/code/hireajackal/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2792:19)
at expr_ops (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/apple/code/hireajackal/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2827:24)
at maybe_conditional (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/apple/code/hireajackal/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2832:20)
at maybe_assign (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/apple/code/hireajackal/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2856:20)
```

The problem is surely with the `scriptsIn` part of gulp file, or i could say that gulp is not able to minify the js files.

I have tried debugging this through multiple ways, but still not able to find the problem. Tried to update/downgrade the relevant packages, but even that didn't help.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this working on an old Laravel 5.1 project.

Mostly this seems to be caused by some new ECMAScript 6+ code you added that uglyfijs is not able to parse. To fix this you need to either use buble or babel to automatically convert the code when you run gulp, or change the code in question to 'regular' js.

See this issue: https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-elixir-webpack-official/issues/34

**Use babel to auto convert your code when runing gulp:**
source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/elixir#babel

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.babel([
        'order.js',
        'product.js'
    ]);
});
```

**or Fix your code, use the following to figure out which script is the culprit:**
`./node_modules/.bin/uglifyjs path/to/resources/assets/js/some_script.js`
Do this for every script until it complains. If it throws an error it will point you to the line number.